# send an url parameter to server from url (PHP/JavaScript)_

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, url

http://nomilead.com/create.php?uid=abc&key=c79a&web_url=http://dinesh707.blogspot.com/

Here im trying to send the url as a parameted "web_url". The shown is an ajax request that sends to a php server back end.

from php end im trying to capture this by

```
$web_url  = $_GET["web_url"];
```

but it does not work.

Please help me out here.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739496/help-on-building-a-basic-php-search-engine/1769351#1769351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URLEncode `web_url`.

In PHP, that would be

```
$url = "http://...&web_url=".urlencode("http://dinesh707.blogspot.com/");
```

in Javascript

```
url = "http://...&web_url="+encodeURIComponent("http://dinesh707.blogspot.com/");
```

Answer (score 1):

it must be    $_GET